# SQL Create table from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Could someone help out with the following.

I have 2 tables, from which I would like to create one table.

> INTO a table, where purchase is ***like* 'table', 'car', 'house',
> 'chair',** with each purchase date, the last known customer location,
> and the time between the first and last purchase, on one line per
> customer.

OUTPUT

```
Customer id, 
last known location,
Last know location date,
purchase 1, 
purchase 1 date 
etc ... , 
date between first and last purchase
```

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

[image: Tables 1 and 2]

[image: Output table]

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: Edited the question. Forum won't allow me to add three images on first post.

Comment: Now added all three tables.

Comment: Is there a max.Number of orders? Or dou you need full flexibility?

Comment: Anyways, the evaluation of the last location and date per customer is quite straight forward via window function, but the pivotting of the orders is a bit more tricky as longs as you do not have a fix number of orders

Answer (score 0):

Just going off of the title of your question, it sounds like you may wish to use a Select Into statement.  For a simple example, assume you have a table of DayNames.  Daynames would have "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" ... "Saturday" as values in it.

if you wanted to create a new table called "WeekDayNames" you would just write a query to do this and add " Into [TableName] " before the FROM Clause.

```
Select DayName.Name as [WeekDayName] 
  Into WeekDayNames 
From DayNames where 
  substring(DayNames.Name,1,1) <> 'S' -- Exclude Saturday and Sunday
```